# function should call only when i reload the page in react

Tags: reactjs

i dont want this shuffle fucntion call to happend  bcoz when i update state its render and my array get shuffled. i want array to be shuffled only on reload, butusing useeffect wont solve problems it makes my array not to shuffle

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useCallback } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import audi from "./images/audi.jpg";
import blackcar from "./images/carinblack.jpg";
import ferrari from "./images/ferrari.jpg";
import lambo from "./images/lambo.jpg";
import rangerover from "./images/rangerover.jpg";

export const Robot = () => {
   const [display,setDisplay]=useState('none')
  let array = [audi, blackcar, ferrari, lambo, rangerover,audi];
  function shuffle(array) {
    let currentIndex = array.length,
      randomIndex;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle.
    while (currentIndex != 0) {
      // Pick a remaining element.
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex--;

      // And swap it with the current element.
      [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
        array[randomIndex],
        array[currentIndex],
      ];
    }

    return array;
  }

shuffle(array)
  const handle=()=>{
    setDisplay('inline')
  }
  const Reset=()=>{
    setDisplay('none')
  }
   
  return (
    <>
      {array.map((data,index)=>{
        return (<>
        <img onClick={handle} src={data}/>
        </>)
      })}
      <h3>
        Please click on the identical tiles to verify that you are not a robot
      </h3>
      <button id='reset' style={{display : display}} onClick={Reset}>Reset</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

i tried useeffect but then reshuffling array not getting shuffled

Answer (score 0):

hmm, it should be using useEffect Rajat, or maybe do you use it wrong, let me show you some example you can try

```
useEffect(()=>{
// your shuffle function
}, 
// keep this empty array so it's only triggered on first load only
[])
```

Hope it's works, thank you